# mod_pagespeed error without the module enabled or ever been installed

Tags: apache, whm

Since day 1 of our new server we have been getting requests for urls with the suffix of pagespeed.(ic/jc/cc) which don't exist.

e.g

> File name too long: [client {CLIENT IP ADDRESS}:58749] AH00036: access
>   to
>   /wp-content,_plugins,_wp-file-upload,_vendor,_datetimepicker,_jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js,qver==4.6+wp-includes,_js,_jquery,_ui,_sortable.min.js,qver==1.11.4+wp-includes,_js,_jquery,_ui,_tabs.min.js,qver==1.11.4+wp-includes,_js,_jquery,_ui,_accordion.min.js,qver==1.11.4.pagespeed.jc.zgb126SHUb.js
>   failed (filesystem path '/home/{DOMAIN HOME
>   DIR}/public_html/wp-content,_plugins,_wp-file-upload,_vendor,_datetimepicker,_jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js,qver==4.6+wp-includes,_js,_jquery,_ui,_sortable.min.js,qver==1.11.4+wp-includes,_js,_jquery,_ui,_tabs.min.js,qver==1.11.4+wp-includes,_js,_jquery,_ui,_accordion.min.js,qver==1.11.4.pagespeed.jc.zgb126SHUb.js')

This looks like javascript aggregation using mod_pagespeed and according to the following links, it looks like an old bug in mod_pagespeed (github was imported and original bug dates ~2010) .

https://github.com/pagespeed/mod_pagespeed/issues/140
https://github.com/pagespeed/mod_pagespeed/issues/9
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mod-pagespeed-discuss/zvsw368HeJw/hjrR1lZmFdMJ

We don't have mod_pagespeed installed in WHM and When running "apachectl -l" it isn't in the compiled apache modules either.

I can't find any traces of this in the files/db of the server and it has been occuring on all of our sites

Has anyone seen this issue or what might be causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**apachectl -l** won't help since it only shows compiled in modules. mod_pagespeed is compiled separately.

Please use this command:

**httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES** (this will show all loaded modules)

You could check if you have any pagespeed.conf file in /etc/httpd/conf or /usr/local/apache/conf or /etc/apache2/conf (I have provided multiple locations since I do not know what cPanel/WHM version you have, if you have apache 2.2.x or apache 2.4.x etc).

You could also issue a **find / -type f -name "*pagespeed*.conf"**

Try to search for pagespeed using: **grep -r -i pagespeed *** in any of the above config locations of your apache web server.

If you do have a pagespeed.conf please edit it and replace ModPagespeed on (which enables mod_pagespeed) with ModPagespeed off (to disable it). Then restart apache /etc/init.d/httpd restart (for CentOS 6.x) or systemctl restart httpd (CentOS 7.x)

For a specific website, go to /home/cpaneluser/public_html and in an .htaccess file add the following directive:

ModPagespeed off

No need to restart apache. If you get a 500 error after saving the .htaccess file for that specifc website, then definetely you do not have mod_pagespeed active.